# File-input can't have clickable zone

Tags: bootstrap-file-input

I have a problem with file-input. When i click in the drop zone, i want shop the file browser.
I found in the doc the option "browseOnZoneClick", but it doesn't work.

```
$("#MYINPUT").fileinput({
            theme: "fas",
            language: "fr",
            browseOnzoneClick: "true",
            allowedFileExtensions: ["xlsx"]
        });
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a maj issue on the option browseOn**Z**oneClick.
I think this is the problem.